# Problema con conexión de NetBeans y MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2, jdbc, mysqlconnector

Tengo un problema conectando NetBeans a MySQL
Tengo instalado el community edition

El mensaje que me aparece es:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las versiones más recientes de MySQL están predeterminadas para caching_sha2_password y no la antigua mysql_native_password que los complementos parecen querer usar.

Creo que puedes convertir a los usuarios, pero para mí es más fácil simplemente borrarlos y luego recrearlos con mysql_native_password como la autenticación predeterminada.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pa$$word';
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Te dejo más información detallada en Ingles > https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html